# Can't read from file

Tags: c++, mfc, fstream

I'm trying to read text from a .log file. I originally have it working a a windows console application but I'm now trying to make a GUI version using MFC. The problem is when i set the while loop as while(file.good()), it completely skips the loop and I'm not sure why because there are no errors with file.open()

```
void Conversion::toXml(CString openPath, CString savePath)
{
CString null("/0");

int c = openPath.GetLength(),q=0;
while(q<c)
{
    if(openPath[q] == '\\')
    {
        openPath.Insert(q,'\\');
        q++;
    }
    q++;
}

CStringA charstr(openPath);
const char* oPath((const char *) charstr);
CStringA charstr2(savePath);
const char* sPath((const char *) charstr2);

ifstream openFile;
ofstream savedFile(sPath);

string recText = "";
string temp;
openFile.open(oPath);

while(openFile.good())
{
    getline(openFile,temp);

    recText = recText + temp;
}
```

smaller version(should compile)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atlstr.h> 


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string recText = "";
string temp;
CString path = "C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\2012-08-281.log";
CStringA charstr(path);
const char* oPath((const char *) charstr);


ifstream xmlDoc (oPath);
ofstream finished ("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\example3.xml");


while(xmlDoc.good())
{
    getline(xmlDoc,temp);

    recText = recText + temp;
}
    finished<<recText<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The string `null` is a string containing three characters: `'/'`, `'0'` and `'\0'`. Is that supposed to be so?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  it doesn't matter:  the string is never used.

Comment: Your filename construction produces an invalid filename, consequently opening of said filename fails, ergo. file is not `.good()`.

Comment: Before you call open print out the name of the file. See if it is what you expect. Looks like you have a few misconceptions about `\\` character in both strings and file path. What is your thinking here?

Comment: You can really help if you reduce the example to a minimal piece of code that (compiles and runs) reproduces the result you see (with the inputs we need to pass in) This code is not compilable (and we don't know what file name you are passing in as a parameter).

Comment: @Loki reduced the code as for a result just being able to get the text from the file and save to another.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you try to escape the backslash when you don't need it, adding unnecessary backslashes in the path. Escaping backslashes is only needed for string *literals*. It might be that Windows doesn't like paths with multiple consecutive backslashes.

Comment: The "simpler" version (trimmed down a bit to remove the unnecessary `CStringA` -> `const char *` nonsense) works just fine for me. What symptoms are you observing? Does `ifstream::is_open` return true?

Comment: @Nik well I had the conversion because in the first block of code i posted the file name is being retrieved using CFileDialog which save a CString so I pass that to the function. ifstream won't take a CString only a const char* or atleast that was the error i was getting. also is_open seems to work it gets caught in a infinite loop so yes?

Comment: sorta lied, when added a watch and some more break points. the while loop initiates 1 time performs getline() and then exits the loop and assigns "" to recText